# Calcular o tamanho da div

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

Estou trabalhando em um script simples de "slider de divs"! Só tem um problema, quando você começa a mover para a esquerda e direita ele corta um pedaço das divs, preciso que mova exatamente de um jeito que ele não corte as divs nem apareça mais do que as 2 divs.

Segue script e [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruvorufn/1/):

```
$( "#seta-direita" ).click(function() {
    if (!$(".slider2").is(':animated')){
        if ($(".slider2").offset().left < 300){
            $(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "+=65px" });
        }
        return false;
    }
});

$( "#seta-esquerda" ).click(function() {
    if (!$(".slider2").is(':animated')){
        if ($(".slider2").offset().left > -1300){
            $(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "-=65px" });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Apurar largura do elemento

Ao invés de estares a animar uma distancia fixa em pixeis, o ideal será apurares a largura que cada elemento do *slider* ocupa e deslocar essa mesma medida.

Em jQuery tens o método [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) que te devolve a [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)+[`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)+[`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) do elemento, permitindo assim obter a largura total que o mesmo ocupa:

```js
// obter largura do slide com margin e padding incluído
var w = $('.slide').outerWidth(true);

// deslocar essa medida para a direita
$(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "+="+w+"px" });

// deslocar essa medida para a esquerda
$(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "-="+w+"px" });
```

```js
var w = $('.slide').outerWidth(true);

$( "#seta-direita" ).click(function() {
if (!$(".slider2").is(':animated'))
{
if ($(".slider2").offset().left < 8)
{
$(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "+="+w+"px" });
}
return false;
}
});

$( "#seta-esquerda" ).click(function() {
if (!$(".slider2").is(':animated'))
{
if ($(".slider2").offset().left > -187)
{
$(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": "-="+w+"px" });
}
return false;
}
});
```

```css
html {
background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

.slider1 {
overflow: hidden;
height: 50px;
width: 130px;
float: left;
}

.slider2 {
background-color: #FFF;
width: 500px;
}

.slide {
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
margin-left: 11px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}

#seta-esquerda {
cursor: pointer;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 13px;
}
#seta-direita {
cursor: pointer;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">
 <div class="slider2">
 
        <div class="slide">a</div>
        <div class="slide">a</div>
        <div class="slide">a</div>
        <div class="slide">a</div>
        <div class="slide">a</div>
 
 </div>
</div>

<div id="setas">
    <div id="seta-esquerda">Esquerda</div>
 <div id="seta-direita">Direita</div>
</div>
```

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/v9qrtesy/).

---

## Otimizar código

Também poderás otimizar o teu código de forma a não fazeres uso de nenhum valor fixo para o controlo da navegação.

Dado que a deslocação dos slides tem por principio não permitir deslocar mais que o primeiro quando a andar para a direita nem permitir deslocar mais que o último quando a andar para a esquerda, o total de slides serve como indicador de controlo.

```js
$('.slide-nav').click(function(){

    var $slider  = $('.slider2');

    if (!$slider.is(':animated')) {      

        var count    = $('.slide').size(),
            slidePx  = $slider.find(':first-child').outerWidth(true),
            slideTo  = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1],
            slidePos = parseInt($slider.css("margin-left")),
            offset   = (slidePx-slidePos)/slidePx;
    
        if (slideTo=="left" && (offset<count)) {
            var direcao = '-';
        }
        else if (slideTo=="right" && (offset>1)) {
            var direcao = '+';
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

        $(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": direcao+"="+slidePx+"px" });
    }
});
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #bcbcbc;
}
.slider1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
}
.slider2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 500px;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 11px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.slide-nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">
 <div class="slider2">
        <div class="slide">A</div>
        <div class="slide">B</div>
        <div class="slide">C</div>
        <div class="slide">D</div>
        <div class="slide">E</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="setas">
    <div class="slide-nav left">Esquerda</div>
 <div class="slide-nav right">Direita</div>
</div>
```

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/kmskpfhu/).

#### HTML

No HTML não existe otimização, existe sim uma alteração nos *triggers* de navegação para permitir a otimização do jQuery e CSS:

```html
<div class="slider1">
    <div class="slider2">
        <div class="slide">A</div>
        <div class="slide">B</div>
        <div class="slide">C</div>
        <div class="slide">D</div>
        <div class="slide">E</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="setas">
    <!-- mesma classe para ação e segunda classe para direção -->
    <div class="slide-nav left">Esquerda</div>
    <div class="slide-nav right">Direita</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

O código em jQuery pode então ficar otimizado conforme em baixo detalhado, de forma a que não existam valores fixos no controlo da deslocação do *slider* o que contribui para uma aplicação mais flexível do mesmo, bem como menor ou nenhuma manutenção quando alteramos as dimensões do *slider* e/ou seus *slides*:

```js
/*!
 * Ao clicar em qualquer seta de navegação
 */
$('.slide-nav').click(function(){

  var $slider  = $('.slider2'); // colocar em cache o elemento a deslocar

  // se não estiver animado
  if (!$slider.is(':animated')) {

    var count    = $('.slide').size(),                            // total de slides
        slidePx  = $slider.find(':first-child').outerWidth(true), // largura de um slide
        slideTo  = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1],           // para onde deslocar
        slidePos = parseInt($slider.css("margin-left")),          // posição atual
        offset   = (slidePx-slidePos)/slidePx;                    // quantos estão deslocados

    // se a deslocar para esquerda e não estamos no último
    if (slideTo=="left" && (offset<count)) {
      var direcao = '-';
    }
    // se a deslocar para direita e não estamos no primeiro
    else if (slideTo=="right" && (offset>1)) {
      var direcao = '+';
    }
    // caso nenhum dos em cima, não fazer nada
    else {
      return;
    }

    // animar para a direção apurada a distância apurada
    $(".slider2").animate({ "margin-left": direcao+"="+slidePx+"px" });
  }
});
```

#### CSS

No CSS a formatação dos *triggers* de navegação passar a ser única o que contribui para um redução de código:

```css
.slide-nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Nos casos em que for necessário aplicar uma formatação especifica a um dos *triggers*, pode-se fazer da seguinte forma:

```
.slide-nav.left {
  /* formatação apenas para "esquerda" */
}

.slide-nav.right {
  /* formatação apenas para "direita" */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está fazendo a conta errada pro deslocamento:

```
largura das caixas + margin+left = deslocamento
50px + 11px = 61px
```

Desloque +/- **61px**, ao invés de 65px.

[Veja o seu jsFiddle atualizado aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/ruvorufn/2/)